# How can I compile my makefile in vc code using windows 11

Tags: c, makefile, compiler-errors, compilation

I'm new in programming and exited to learn new things!
I wanted to create and run makefile in c, to see how it's working, but I'm having the same problem again and again. I will send the picture and the source (from geeksforgeeks) that I'm using.... Thanks a lot .

[image: 1]

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-make-utility-to-build-c-projects/

I tried to run makefile and then I wanted to use the commands in makefile to see how they r working.

Comment: Post data as text here instead of external images.  Presumably you need to install make.  You should tag this with windows and probably remove the c tag as it's not a question about c.  See https://www.technewstoday.com/install-and-use-make-in-windows/

Comment: ok. I'm still trying to solve it, it's the same error..

Comment: You will need to explain what you have done, say, by updating your question, also remember to comment on the answer otherwise authors of  answers may not see it.

Comment: I didn't know About Ubuntu. I just downloaded it and set the setting. I was in the windows, and now I easily can use command for Linux. sorry for my not correct question I just didn't know that they r different...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [install make](https://technewstoday.com/install-and-use-make-in-windows), or if it's already installed, update you search path for commands to where it's installed.